# python etree insert, append and SubElement

Tags: python, xml, lxml, elementtree

I want to create an element tree like this in Python:

```
<parent>
  <child/>
  <child/>
  <child/>
</parent>
```

I want to use it as an empty template that I can work on later. However, I cannot insert or append multiple `<child>` element to the `<parent>` element, though `etree.SubElement` works. To be more specific:

This produces `<parent><child/></parent>`, i.e., only one `<child>` got inserted:

```
root = etree.Element('root')
child = etree.Element('child')
for i in range(3):
  root.insert(0,child)
```

This does not work either and produce the same result as above:

```
root = etree.Element('root')
child = etree.Element('child')
for i in range(3):
  root.append(child)
```

This works:

```
root = etree.Element('root')
for i in range(3):
  etree.SubElement('child')
```

I don't understand why I cannot insert or append an element for multiple times.

Comment: You are using the same object each time in your first examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you need to create new element objects to append them to the root, otherwise it is the same element that you append twice, which has no effect :

```
root = etree.Element('root')

for i in range(3):
    child = etree.Element('child')
    root.append(child)
```

Hope this helps.